# How to add options to multiple dropdownlist with same id when add the dynamic raws

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

When `addrow()` is called we want to add dynamic rows using `id="rowTemplate"`.
I want to load data to dropdownlist `(id="selectitem")` using `"myfunction()"`.
But here issue is every time when `"myfunction()"` is called the data is loaded only for dropdownlist of the first row :

```js
//adding dynamic rows

function addRow() {

  $('#orderItem').append($('#rowTemplate').html());

  console.log($('#rowTemplate').html());
  myFunction();

}

function myFunction() {

  document.getElementById("selectitem").options.length = 0

  var SupID = document.getElementById("selectSup").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Supplier Id: " + SupID;

  var dataString = 'SupID='+ SupID;

  // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
  var postForm1 = { //Fetch form data
    'functionName': "itemLoad",
    'SupID': SupID
  };


  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'suppierOrderdb.php',
    data: postForm1,
    //dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {

      var dd = data;



      var data = (typeof dd) == 'string' ? eval('(' + dd + ')') : dd;


      for (var i = 0; i < dd.length; i++) {


        $('#selectitem').append($('<option>',
                                  {
          value: data[i].ItemId,
          text : data[i].ItemId +" - "+ data[i].ItemName
        }));


      }


    }
    , error: function (e) {
      alert(e);
    }
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="selectitem" class="control-label col-xs-2">Item Name</label>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <select name='selectItem[]' class='form-control form-control-sm' id='selectitem'>
      </select>
    </div>

    <label for="Qty" class="control-label col-xs-2">QTY</label>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <input class="form-control" name="Qty[]" type="text" value="" id="Qty">
    </div>

  </div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Use classes instead of ids when you want to refer to multiple items.

Comment: `id` should be unique in the same document.

Comment: Please add relevant HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

`id` should be unique in the same document alse also you got an invalid HTML and the first element with duplicate `id` will be called, so replace your dep `id`'s by common class in :

```
$('#orderItem').append($('#rowTemplate').html());
```

Could be :

```
$('#orderItem').append($('.rowTemplate').html());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is that not what you're looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

Like wlh and Zakaria Acharki said, ID's are unique within the DOM.

Take a look at [this link from css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/) to learn more about the differences between Classes and IDs.

Also, to access a class in jQuery, use `$('.classname')`, replacing the `#` for IDs with a `.` for classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[id=selectitem]').append($('<option>', {
  value: data[i].ItemId,
  text: data[i].ItemId + " - " + data[i].ItemName
}));
```

Comment: It would be good if this answer could contain some sort of description which says how it answers the question.